# Finding duplicate values in columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find duplicate values so that if a player has two rows with their username in it but different ID's it shows in results. The column is called last_nickname.

What would be the query to check this?

Comment: How do your tables look like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT 
    col, 
    COUNT(col)
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY col
HAVING COUNT(col) > 1;
```

Reference

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find-duplicate-values/